# Mahalanobis distance in sklearn DistanceMetrics got Singular matrix error

Tags: python, sklearn-pandas, mahalanobis

I'm trying to calculate Mahalanobis distance using following simple code:

```
from sklearn.neighbors import DistanceMetric
import numpy as np

X = [[0, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5]]
dist = DistanceMetric.get_metric('mahalanobis', V=np.cov(X))
print(dist.pairwise(X))
```

But I got an error said:

```
>>>numpy.linalg.linalg.LinAlgError: Singular matrix
```

I'm not quite understand what's going on.
Thanks for any suggestion.